# Combine associative array/object in JS without erasing numerically indexed values $.extend()

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using `$.extend(true, {}, obj1, obj2)`, the resulting object erases any numerically-indexed data up to the number of results in `obj2`.

A sample call to `$.extend()` would be like this:

Then take this sample data for instance:

```
 var base_json_obj = {
    'regions': [
   'NC',
    '-Greensboro',
    'VA',
    '-Richmond'
  ],
  'vehicles': [
    'Ford:Escape',
    'Nissan:Altima'
  ],
  'turnover': {
    'min': '0d',
    'max': '5d'
  }
 };

 var new_json_obj = {
    'regions': [
    'FL',
    '-Miami'
  ],
  'vehicles': [
    'Hyundai:Sonata'
  ],
  'turnover': {
    'min': '1d',
    'max': '6d'
  }
 };


var resulting_object = $.extend(true, {}, base_json_obj, new_json_obj);
```

The resulting object is

```
{
  'regions': [
    'FL',
    '-Miami',
    'VA',
    '-Richmond'
  ],
  'vehicles': [
    'Hyundai:Sonata',
    'Nissan:Altima'
  ]
  'turnover': {
    'min': '1d',
    'max': '6d'
  },
}
```

And here is the expected output. Notice that `regions` has all 6 values and that `vehicles` has all 3 values.

```
{
  'regions': [
    'NC',
    '-Greensboro',
    'VA',
    '-Richmond',
    'FL',
    '-Miami'
  ],
  'vehicles': [
    'Ford:Escape',
    'Nissan:Altima',
    'Hyundai:Sonata'
  ]
  'turnover': {
    'min': '1d',
    'max': '6d'
  },
}
```

Is there a way to modify the call to `$.extend()` or use `$.merge()` in some way to achieve this?

Comment: Do both objects have the same properties (regions, vehicles, turnover), or are there any additional properties in one of the objects ?

Answer (score 1):

`$.extend(true, ...)` will treat the Arrays like an object, using `value` and `index`, so just like `'min'`, the key of `0` will be replaced.

You'll need to write something that handles this case. The `$.extend()` function is relatively complicated, but a good place to start:

- [Github - jQuery Core Source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop :

```js
var base_json_obj = {
    'regions': [
   'NC',
    '-Greensboro',
    'VA',
    '-Richmond'
  ],
  'vehicles': [
    'Ford:Escape',
    'Nissan:Altima'
  ],
  'turnover': {
    'min': '0d',
    'max': '5d'
  }
 };

 var new_json_obj = {
    'regions': [
    'FL',
    '-Miami'
  ],
  'vehicles': [
    'Hyundai:Sonata'
  ],
  'turnover': {
    'min': '1d',
    'max': '6d'
  }
 };


var resulting_object={};
for (key in base_json_obj) {
    // the values from base and new json objects respectively
    var val1 = base_json_obj[key], val2 = new_json_obj[key];
    resulting_object[key] = Array.isArray(val1)? // if array
    val1.concat(val2): // concatenate them, else (objects)
    Object.assign({}, val1, val2); // assign the second object to the first one
}
console.log(resulting_object);
```

Comment: Would be nice if `turnover` wasn't hard coded into it and it could expand to any numerical/textual index object.

Comment: What about checking for all values, if array, `concat()`, else `Object.assign()`.